# Partial search updater frame when large title used

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller, preferslargetitles, large-title

When I use a SearchController with a different searchResultsController and I have the large titles active, I get a partial view of the search view controller. It appears that the target controller is drawn taking into account the height of the navigationbar even if it is then collapsed. I tried a bit of everything but without being able to view it correctly
[image]